# Is there any way to make FloatingActionBar Scrolling with SliverAppBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is my code , the fab will be fixed how to make it display as in android.

```
 MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: buildSliverAppBar(),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endTop,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: You should put the code instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what is your use case in which you want to use such a layout where you want your `FloatingActionButton` to be scrolled with `SliverAppBar`. But here's how to achieve it  :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: height * 0.15,
          flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text('Scrolling Scaffold'),
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            height: height * 0.9,
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$_counter',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                tooltip: 'Increment',
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Comment: In Android ,if the fab was set anchor to appbar , when the appbar expanding , the fab will move too ,keeping in the bottom of appbar,

Comment: Can you please explain or show what do you really want to do ?

Comment: we can set "app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"" in android xml ,this make fab scroll with apbar when expanding